# Vuforia hide marker

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

Suppose you have a marker for your Vuforia AR application and when the digital object appears, you want to hide or cover the marker, like so:
https://youtu.be/eTLr8mN3_yw?t=15

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this as one of those coloring book AR examples. Rough explanation would be reading the colors of fingers and wrapping around the target with that color.

Take a look at here https://github.com/maximrouf/RegionCapture